# How can we speed up for loops in Pulp

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

My Problem has 1500 constraints and 1000 equations and solution is time sensitive, adding constraints to my model via for loop is taking the significant amount of time.

Presently I am adding constraints and equations to model like

```py
    for i in range(6000): 
        lputpay +=(x[i]*lput(pp[i],pst[i]))  #x[i] is pulp variable
```

This thing takes 60% time of the solution process, I have tried Numba, Cython but doesn't support non-python objects.

Comment: why `< 0`? Is it required or something else.

Comment: updated the code example to actual

Comment: It's hard to read out potential bottlenecks from that snipped. What's pp, pst and especially lput? Are those simple random-access things or more expensive calls (e.g. lput)? Assuming random-access, i would expect your solving-time is < 1 sec if it's dominated by this loop?

Comment: lput multiples pp and pst, not much of a bottleneck its python for loop iterationस which are taking time

Comment: Solving time is yes less than one, but in my case every 100 ms of time counts

Comment: If model-building is your bottleneck, pulp is probably the wrong tool. It's easy to use and well-packaged, but i doubt efficiency was it's main design-goal. CyLP for example, which i won't recommend due to missing dev and harsh setup, would allow to get rid of those loops completely as it's allowing much more low-level access to the model.

Comment: yes the model building is bottleneck

Comment: The example is not a constraint. You probably can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and did not find a way to rectify it using Python. Python is a slow language unless you're able to find a clever way to leverage libraries. Since you've already tried Numba and Cython, you've exhausted most of your available options on that front.

I solved my problem by switching languages to use Julia's [JuMP](http://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/v0.19.0/). Julia hasn't always worked out well for me (I usually can get a significant speed boost by switching to C++), but turned out to be perfect for this problem: the representation was still high-level, but the performance was *much* better than Python.

A quick example:

```
using JuMP
using Cbc
lpModel = Model(solver = CbcSolver(seconds = 3600))
@variable(lpModel, x >= 5)
@variable(lpModel, y >= 6)
@constraint(lpModel, x+y == 18)
@constraint(lpModel, 20x + 30y <= 470)
@objective(lpModel, Max, 2x + 3y)
status = JuMP.solve(lpModel)
println("Number of Tea Cups: $(getvalue(x))")
println("Number of Coffee Mugs : $(getvalue(y))")
```